# Django1.4 with Celery: A. Sqlite3 database as broker possible? B. Celery versions necessary to install?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-1.4

I'm running into all sorts of errors when following the [official celery guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) for django projects. Before going into more detail of the errors I encountered I would like to be clear on the following issues:

1. Do you only need to install `django-celery` or do you need to install `celery` as well?
   This [official guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) does not mention you should. I have read guides installing both and other not mentioning installing plain `celery` at all.
2. I am using `sqlite3` as my database in my development environment, can you use an sqlite3 database with celery as a broker? The last person in [this thread](http://www.thebirdietoldme.com/userActions/thread/Question.aspx?id=6959702) seems to hint it's not possible.

I am using `django1.4` and `django-celery 3.0.11`

Btw the latest of a series of errors I an into is `DatabaseError: no such table: djkombu_queue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Running `pip install django-celery` will install `celery` as well.
2. I uninstalled `south` and dropped the table `south_migrationhistory`. Then reran `syncdb` and everything worked as in the documentation. I don't know exactly why this was causing an error though. So the answer to the second question is yes, `Sqlite3` is able to work as a broker for celery.